# inflating layout item

Tags: android, layout-inflater, customdialog

i'm sorry if this question is a repeat.
I have a problem:

I have one main_activity with main_layout.xml. 
I have a `TextView` and `SeekBar1` in it.
I added a menu with a `custom_dialog_layout` which has a seekbar2.
`Dialog` shows that custom_dialog with seek bar.

when doing this:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resize_dialog,null);
seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
```

application force closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resize_dialog,null); 
 seekbar = (SeekBar)view. findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
```

/** Add that inflated view to AlertDialog */

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    builder.setView(view);
```

use this for cancelling Dialog.
i.e dialog.dismiss();

```
.setPositiveButton(
                getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: It works for the first time..if I try opening dialog again without closing app,I got another problem: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Answer (score 0):

replace with following code.

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resize_dialog,null); 
seekbar = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
```

you need to pass reference of `view` to find id.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code.

```
    private class ViewHolder {          
    SeekBar seekbar ;

}


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.resize_dialog, null);
         holder=new ViewHolder();
         holder.seekbar = (SeekBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
         convertView.setTag(holder);
          }
      else  
    holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


      return convertView;
```